# Where can I find a dataset for international borders that includes national waters?

Tags: borders

I'm trying to find a `.shp` file that not only includes international land boundaries, but also the water boundaries, extending out to international waters.  Does such a thing exist?  I'm not even sure of what terms to search for.

Currently, I'm operating using a world borders map which is mostly good, but when our mobile users approach the ocean and their GPS flakes out a bit, our system can't place them within a country.  I figure the best way to fix this is to used a dataset that will always place the national border well away from dry land (and cell towers for their phone).

This project isn't making any money, so I'm hoping for free :-)

Comment: You might try this question out over on the Open Data SE: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably referring to the Exclusive Economic Zones ([EEZs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEZ)) of each country, which generally delineate the boundary between international waters and national waters. [Marineregions.org](http://www.marineregions.org/index.php) has probably the best EEZ data freely available, I'd start there, I've used it successfully in a variety of analyses.

Comment: EEZs are very different than maritime boundary. EEZs confer to a country the exclusive exploitation below the surface, while the waters remain international waters. To the contrary, countries have full sovereignty within their maritime boundaries.